# Ember action preventing checkbox value from setting

Tags: javascript, ember.js, checkbox

In my ember application I would like to render a set of checkboxes dynamically via a loop and disable any unselected checkboxes if 2 of the checkboxes have been checked.

I am having problems with setting a value to 'true' when a checkbox is selected that has a change action. For the following example `checkbox.value` does not get set when the checkbox is selected.

```
{{ input type="checkbox" disabled=checkbox.disabled checked=checkbox.value change=(action "disableCheckboxes" val)}} {{checkbox.label}}
```

However when I remove the action it does get set:

```
{{ input type="checkbox" disabled=checkbox.disabled checked=checkbox.value}} {{checkbox.label}}
```

[Full example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MGadd/kaps9zqx/)

How can I set the value while still running the action? Or is the a better way to disable the unchecked checkbox when 2 have already been selected?

Comment: Why not use radiobuttons for this? They should automatically change their checked state if another one is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first you can use an action. Checkout [this ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/eb3c475bf97b96758c97057808fa1711?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

---

But I would recommend to directly bind your value to your target object. [See here](https://ember-twiddle.com/001ce0dea777cd739aa430657213f3cf?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C).

The idea is basically to wrap your array and calculate the isDisabled in the wrapping:

```
boxes:[{id:1,value:true},{id:2},{id:3}],
boxArr: Ember.computed('boxes.@each.value', {
  get() {
    let disableOthers = Ember.get(this, 'boxes').filterBy('value', true).get('length') >= 2;
    return Ember.get(this, 'boxes').map(origin => {
      return {
        origin,
        disabled: disableOthers && !origin.value,
      };
    });
  }
}),
```

Then you can just use it in your template:

```
{{#each boxArr as |box|}}
  {{input type="checkbox" disabled=box.disabled checked=box.origin.value}} {{box.origin.id}}
{{/each}}
```

---

A third way to archive is with a helper. You can just have a computed property saying if all checkboxes with `value=false` should be disabled, and then use an `and` and `not` helper to set `disabled=(and disableFalseCheckboxes (not box.value)`. Checkout [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) for that.